# chart.js - making a grouped pie chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to make a pie chart like the image below, using chart.js however, cannot seem to get there.
[this is what i wanna make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMfyl.png)
I have seen some d3.js plugins that helps with this however, I cannot learn that in time so whatever i can do with chart.js.

can i get some help please. i am struggling with this, not sure if this should be simple or i am just over complicating thing. as for as i am aware i am taking the logical approach

below is my code.

```js
    <script>
      const documentType = [];
      const documentRevision = [];
      const docTypeRev = [];
      const docTypeTotal = [];
      const percentage = [];

      showDoughnutChart();
      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      // START OF DOUGHNUT CHART
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      async function showDoughnutChart() {
        await getDataDoughnutGraph();
        const doughnutChart = document
          .getElementById("myChart")
          .getContext("2d");

        let chart3a = new Chart(doughnutChart, {
          type: "doughnut",
          data: {
            labels: documentType,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "Some metric",
                backgroundColor: [
                  "#619E98",
                  "#4164BE",
                  "#7D35CA",
                  "#B2A44D",
                  "#946B76",
                  "#6C9D62",
                  "#C6B139",
                  "#2688D9",
                  "#D62963",
                  "#CCBF33",
                  "#adff2f",
                  "#B6495D",
                ],
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderRadius: 5,
                offset: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                cutout: "50%",
                data: docTypeRev,
              },

              {
                label: "Some metric",
                backgroundColor: [
                  "#619E98",
                  "#4164BE",
                  "#7D35CA",
                  "#B2A44D",
                  "#946B76",
                  "#6C9D62",
                  "#C6B139",
                  "#2688D9",
                  "#D62963",
                  "#CCBF33",
                  "#adff2f",
                  "#B6495D",
                ],
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderRadius: 5,
                offset: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                cutout: "50%",
                data: [1, 1, 1],
              },
            ],
          },
          options: {
            plugins: {
              legend: {
                display: true,
                position: "right",
              },
              title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Tag Distrubution by Class",
                color: "black",
              },
            },
            layout: {
              padding: 10,
            },
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            responsive: true,
          },
        });
      }

      async function getDataDoughnutGraph() {
        const responseLine = await fetch("stats_doc_type_Rev.csv");

        const chart3el = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
        const data = await responseLine.text();

        const table = data.split("\n").slice(1);
        table.forEach((row) => {
          //split by line
          const columns = row.split(",");
          // split by column
          const documentTypeEX = columns[0];
          const documentRevisionEX = columns[1];
          const docTypeRevEX = columns[2];
          const docTypeTotalEX = columns[3];
          const percentage_EX = columns[4];

          //pushing into global variables
          documentType.push(documentTypeEX);
          documentRevision.push(documentRevisionEX);
          docTypeRev.push(docTypeRevEX);
          docTypeTotal.push(docTypeTotalEX);
          percentage.push(percentage_EX);

          // console.log(percentage_EX);
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
      .chartMenu {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 40px;
        background: #1a1a1a;
        color: rgba(255, 26, 104, 1);
      }
      .chartMenu p {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
      .chartCard {
        width: 100vw;
        height: calc(100vh - 40px);
        background: rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .chartBox {
        width: 700px;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: solid 3px rgba(255, 26, 104, 1);
        background: white;
      }
    </style>
```

```html
    <div class="chartMenu">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="chartCard">
      <div class="chartBox">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"
    ></script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72901611/2358409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could add 2 datasets, 1 grouped and 1 with all values.
To show the labels, you can use https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/.

```js
const multiLeveData = {
  firstLevel: {
    data: [15, 10]
  },
  secondLevel: {
    data: [20, 30]
  },
};
const dataForDataset = function(grouped) {
  const result = [];
  for (const key of Object.keys(multiLeveData)) {
    if (grouped) {
      result.push(multiLeveData[key].data.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0));
    } else {
      multiLeveData[key].data.forEach(function(item){
        result.push(item);
      })
    }
  }
  return result;
}
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "doughnut",
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Some metric",
        backgroundColor: [
          "#619E98",
          "#619E98",
          "#7D35CA",
          "#7D35CA"
        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,
        offset: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        cutout: "50%",
        data: dataForDataset(),
      },
      {
        label: "Some metric",
        backgroundColor: "#4164BE",
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,
        offset: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        cutout: "50%",
        data: dataForDataset(true),
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      tooltip: {
        display: false,
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Tag Distrubution by Class",
        color: "black",
      },
      datalabels: {
        color: 'white',
        font: {
          size: 16
        }
      }
    },
    layout: {
      padding: 10,
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    responsive: true,
  },
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.1.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400" tabindex="1"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. EXACTLY, what im looking for. THANKS guys!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!