# Doughnut chartjs: how to display sub-group inside group?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Does anyone know how to make a doughnut chart like this?
Let say we have 3 labels like this, inside each label contains its name and a sub-group (contains 12 childs with name and value of their own). I want to show the values of sub-group in the chart, but values must share same label
This example means there are total 36 values to display, but each 12 values must share same label (36 values = 3 group). When I turn off 1 label, 12 values of that label must also be turned off. The chart must only display 3 labels

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaOQ8.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70721322/2358409

Comment: That answer is not right, I need only display 1 circle, no inner circles allowed.
Futhermore, that answer is still not correct, since some arcs display wrong label

Comment: Yes, my comment is not the solution to your problem, rather just a hint to help you go one step further.